# How to use for loops in strings with cancatenation or any other way would be great?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have been trying to fetch the result of for loop and then use that in the string..but not getting how to do it so if you people please help me to do so..! It will be too kindful..!

besides here is my code..you people will get some idea what I am really trying to do please?

as :

```
$email->Body      = 'Form Submitted By Client : '.$client.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.'Form Name : '.ucwords($formlink).PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.
for ($i=0;$i<$form_questions_no;$i++) { 
$i_query = $i+1; 
echo  '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</br>Question No '.$i_query.' : '.$rows['question'.$i_query].'</br>Ans '.$i_query.' : '.$answers[$i].'</br>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</br>'; };
```

but it's not working getting error please..so how can I do it please?

Comment: Break it up into parts and put it all together. Don't try to do everything all at once.

Comment: @JohnConde : any possible way would be great please..! Can you post an anwer with well explanation to the issue..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't concatenation with a loop.

a loop it's just there to indicate a block of actions to be done several times. here what you try to do is concatenate several times,  so just put the concatenation inside of the loop !

```
  $email->Body      = 'Form Submitted By Client : '.$client.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.'Form Name :'.ucwords($formlink).PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;


for ($i=0;$i<$form_questions_no;$i++) { 
  $i_query = $i+1; 
  $email->Body .= '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</br>Question No '.$i_query.' : '.$rows['question'.$i_query].'</br>Ans '.$i_query.' : '.$answers[$i].'</br>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</br>';

 }
```

the ".=" operator is a shortcut :
 $a .= "text";
is equals to  : 
 $a = $a."text";

everything is clear ?

Comment: Thanks it worked out..! just got it one minute ago before your answer and was thinking to post answer to my own question but when refreshed page so you already had answered it the same way I was thinking to post the answer..!